# In Sass, what's the difference between the @mixin and @extend directives?

Tags: css, sass

I just finished with the Sass [guide](http://sass-lang.com/guide).
The guide explains mixins:

> ..A mixin lets you make groups of CSS declarations that you want to
> reuse throughout your site. You can even pass in values to make your
> mixin more flexible.

and extend:

> .. This is one of the most useful features of Sass. Using @extend lets
> you share a set of CSS properties from one selector to another ..

It looks like 'extend' may be implemented in 'mixin' (it seems 'mixin' is extend of 'extend' :-) ).

```css
// @extend
.message {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #333;
}

.success {
  @extend .message;
  border-color: green;
}

.error {
  @extend .message;
  border-color: red;
}

.warning {
  @extend .message;
  border-color: yellow;
}

// @mixin
@mixin message($color) {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #333;
  border-color: $color;
}

.success { @include message(green); }

.error { @include message(red); }

.warning { @include message(yellow); }
```

and even more because mixins have params.
But on the other hand the processed CSS is not exactly the same. But it will be same style effect on the DOM.

```css
/* extend processed */
.message, .success, .error, .warning {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #333; }

.success {
  border-color: green; }

.error {
  border-color: red; }

.warning {
  border-color: yellow; }

/* mixin processed */

.success {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #333;
  border-color: green; }

.error {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #333;
  border-color: red; }

.warning {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #333;
  border-color: yellow; }
```

My question is how do these features differ?
When should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From http://blog.nakulrajput.com/mixins-extends-and-placeholders/:

**@mixin**

Here is **how mixins work**. Definition and usage:

```
@mixin awesome {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    @include awesome;
}

p {
    @include awesome;
}
```

The snippets above produce the following CSS:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

p {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

To make things a little bit more interesting, **we could make our mixin accept parameters**. Even better, we are able to define default values if the mixin is called without arguments.

```
@mixin awesome($w: 100%, $h: 100%) {
    width: $w;
    height: $h;
}

body {
    @include awesome(960px);
}

p {
    @include awesome;
}
```

The result will be similar, but the width of the body is different.

```
body {
    width: 960px;
    height: 100%;
}

p {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

> If you use mixins, the styles in them are duplicated for each selector.

Mixins are very helpful if you need to change or calculate something in the final output, *for example* if you need to apply `border-radius` to several elements.

However, in some other cases there is a lot of duplicative code, which could be avoided if you use **@extend**.

```
**@extend**

.awesome {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    @extend .awesome;
}

p {
    @extend .awesome;
}
```

It's similar, isn't it. In Sass it looks almost identical, but the CSS the result is:

```
.awesome, body, p {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Shorter than the version using a mixin. You can't pass parameters during the extending, but that's not the idea actually.

> **@extend** should be used in those places where you want to share properties between the elements.

Comment: [csswizardry.com/2014/11/when-to-use-extend-when-to-use-a-mixin/](https://csswizardry.com/2014/11/when-to-use-extend-when-to-use-a-mixin/) - great post on the issue

Answer (score 3):

Well, Mixin is like function that can do some work and output processed result while `extend` is like pre-defined `cop-paste` code

Answer (score 2):

In programming terms:
 @include is like calling a function with or without parameters
 @extend is like Inheritance

Function means, every time we call the function, the body of the function gets duplicated as we might pass dynamic information in the form of parameters. so you would get a **Copy** of the body.

Inheritance means, there is no duplication and we get a **Reference** instead of copy. so who ever extends that reference would get the same body.